# Como usar popover em texto sem usar Href

Tags: javascript, popover

Boa tarde, como eu coloco um `popover` em um texto sem usar um `<a href ...` ?
É possível ?

Meu código:

```
<div class="row">
    <div role="main" class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3" align="center">
        <img width="120" height="120" src='img/trab_suporte.png'/></br></br>
        <h5><center><a href="#" title="Responsável por atender os clientes, identificar, corrigir e reportar erros nos sistemas." rel="tooltip"><img src="img/info.png" width="20px" height="20px"/> Suporte Técnico</a> - <b>1</b></center></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o title em outro elemento? O que aconteceu?

Comment: Vc quer dizer, em um elemento clicável?

Comment: Vc está usando um plugin pra isso ou é apenas o `title` padrão do HTML?

Comment: 1 - A mágica é no rel, o title somente não resolve;
2 - Um elemento sem link no caso;
3 - Estou usando algumas importações padrões pra esse componente

Resolvi da seguinte forma:


<span data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Aqui vai o contéudo que deseja aparecer."><img src="img/info.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></span>Desenvolvimento</a> - <b>?</b>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que aparenta, você está utilizando o Bootstrap, estão vou dar uma solução em Bootstrap. Nele, existe o componente `Popover`, que você pode ler melhor sua definição [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/).

Abaixo está um código de como você pode utilizar em um outro elemento, no caso um simples `<span>`, sem ter que utilizar `<a href ...`:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Aqui vai o contéudo que deseja aparecer.">
   Clique Aqui
</span>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, coloquei uma imagem no meio e ficou como eu queria, muito obrigado!